# Multithreading in Apache Beam : Reading Files in Seperate Threads

Tags: apache-beam

We have a requirement to create separate threads for reading multiple files.

1. Thread 1 can read file 1 and create `PCollection<String>`. Can I execute a `Pardo Operation` in a multithreaded environment. and create a `PCollection < String,String >` from `PCollection< String >`?
2. Thread 2 and complete the same operation from Thread 1 but on a different file File 2.
3. Join output of File1 and File 2 in the main thread after Thread 1 and Thread 2 operation is completed.

Could you please tell whether this is possible and it is a recommended approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want can be done with Beam. In the Beam model, you do not define *how* you want your operations to run, but rather, *what* operations you want to perform; then Beam, and the underlying runner takes care of managing threads.

That's why you generally shouldn't manage your own threads to read files in Beam. You should use `TextIO` to read from plain text files, and the `TextIO` module should read the files in parallel.

There are a few cases when your files will not be able to be read in parallel:

1. Your files are compressed. This means that the file needs to be simultaneously decompressed and read, and can be read from different offsets simultaneously.
2. You have too many files (1000s). If you have thousands or tens of thousands of files, you may want to use `TextIO.readAll` instead of the normal `TextIO` implementation, because keeping track of thousands of files that are being read in parallel can overwhelm the system.

Let me know if you are using non-plain text files, or other kind of source.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. Our use case is we are reading  10 large  input files in GB size and convert them into PCollection<String>. and then we use joins to extract information based on primary key and finally we create set of output files.
Following is the transformation.
1) File1 - > PCollection<String> ---> PCollection<KV<Primary Key, Row Data>>(to use join we are converting PColeciton<String> to a primary key KV structure).
2) Can we use multithreading to read multiple files in parallel?
3) Will we get any performance benefit of using multithreading to read large input files in parallel.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: 1) We are using .txt files which are GB's in size.

2) Could you please clarify the following. Our implementation looks like the following

PCollection< String > FileData1 = TextIO.read().from(File1.txt);
PCollection< String > FileData2 = TextIO.read().from(File2.txt);
PCollection< String > FileData3 = TextIO.read().from(File3.txt);

Could you please confirm that reading from File1,File2,File3 occurs in parallel.

Comment: I believe this should read your files in parallel. Do you feel that it's not doing that? If you are using dataflow, you can provide a Job ID, and I can take a look.

Comment: Hi Pablo, I am using currently Apex Runner for testing. Please find the code,expected behavior,current Behavior details.

Code:

LOG.info("File1 Read Start");
PCollection< String > FileData1 = TextIO.read().from(File1.txt);
LOG.info("Completed Reading File1");
LOG.info("File2 Read Start");
PCollection< String > FileData2 = TextIO.read().from(File2.txt);
LOG.info("Completed Reading File2");


Expected Behavior:
Log statements shoud be displayed in any sequence since multithreading is internally used.

Current Bevior:
Log Statements are displayed one after the other in sequence

Comment: What you need to do is use the Pipeline object here. And Beam first builds the pipeline (e.g. defines a graph), and later executes it. Something like so:  `pipeline.apply(TextIO.read()...)`, and later on `pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish()`. The file will only be read after `pipeline.run()`, which is when the job is submitted.
I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes Pablo, I am doing the same thing. pipeline.apply("ReadLines",

Comment: That means that your `LOG.info()` calls will run serially during pipeline construction. The multithreaded read of files will occur during pipeline execution, after you call `pipeline.run`. That's why your LOGs appear in order.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. This is what exactly we were trying to understand.