# Efficiency of Apache Beam Cloud Dataflow reading all data

Tags: python-3.x, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a GCS folder which has 1000s of new line delimited json files. I have to write a beam program to read those 1000s of json files and process and write to some other GCS bucket/folder. I'm using apache beam with cloud dataflow as backend to the job.

Here's how I'm reading the json files from the GCS bucket:

```
(pcoll | "read data gcs" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(self.bucket + "*", coder=JsonCoder()))
```

My Question is when I give `*` during the reading of the files, wouldn't it be too much to read all the files into memory? Or how does beam read very large data?

Comment: There are some details on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424108/multithreading-in-apache-beam-reading-files-in-seperate-threads